# Updating a Table by counting results from another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the table T1 by counting the results of a SQL Query from another table T2.

This is the query I came up with but it does not seem to work:

```
UPDATE T1 set Stock = (select count (ID_Item)

FROM T2, T1

WHERE   T2.ID_Product=T1.ParentSKU AND
   T2.Name='' AND
   T2.Returned=''
```

I am getting 0 for the result even though I know it should not be.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE T1
    SET Stock = (SELECT count(ID_Item)
                 FROM T2
                 WHERE T2.ID_Product = T1.ParentSKU AND
                       T2.Name = '' AND
                       T2.Returned = ''
                );
```

You should not repeat the reference to `T1` in the correlated subquery.  You need a connection between the subquery and the table being updated.

Comment: Thanks that works great but I realized that I need to add one more query from another table T3 in the select count. How can I do this?

Comment: @PierreS. . . . Ask *another* question.  Don't ask questions in comments and don't change questions after they've been answered (that can invalidate answers which draws downvotes).